# Web request from WPF program to local IIS seems to hang IIS

Tags: c#, wpf, iis, iis-7

This is a very weird issue--

I have a WPF program.

This program make a very simple web call like this:

```
string result = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://localhost/....");
```

After a minute, this times out and throws an exception.

The same URL works fine when I call it from a web browser-- but the strange part is this:After I make this call, the App Pool running the destination app (IIS 7.5) seems to be hung ...

When I run the web app in IIS express instead of IIS, everything is fine.

Before I make the call in the WPF program, I can hit the URL from a browser fine.  Afterwards, hitting the URL causes the browser (IE11 or Chrome) to spin indefinitely.

The App Pool is hung until I stop and start it from the IIS manager.  Recycling it doesn't seem to work.

I can't imagine what is going wrong here.

Comment: iis logs show anything interesting?

Comment: iis logs don't show anything interesting.  I've found that the web app works fine when run in IIS express.

Comment: did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748701/downloadstring-gives-a-timeout-on-a-https-url-seeming-to-work-in-a-browser)?